# Change Icon for Window Manager at login

Tags: lightdm

is there any way to change the icons for a Window Manager at the login screen? This one:

[image]

The files are in /usr/share/unity-greeter/ that I know, but can I change the Icon for a WM if it has none?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `unity-greeter-badges` provides icons (or badges, as they're called in this context) for about 30 window managers. `unity-greeter-badges` is available from the default repositories starting with Ubuntu 15.04. deb packages for Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10 can be found [in this blog post](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/01/unity-greeter-badges-brings-missing-session-icons-ubuntu-login-screen).

You can also add your own badges. To do that, you need to know the X session name of the window manager in question. Say you want to create a badge for 'xfce' sessions. Then you need your badge as a png image sized 22 x 22 pixel. Name that image file after the pattern `custom_SESSIONNAME_badge.png`, in this example `custom_xfce_badge.png`. Put the image to `/usr/share/unity-greeter`, and it should be recognized automatically.

Comment: Adding a custom_SESSIONNAME_badge.png worked perfectly. Thanks! I added an i3_custom_badge.png and it got added nicely.

Answer (score 1):

In there, there should be a file named "cof.png". But you **cannot** edit the file in the normal way. Here are the steps to do it:

#### 1. Press Alt + F2 and type:

```
gksu nautilus
```

...then do what it prompts you to do.

#### 2. Go to the `unity-greeter` directory

...and look for `cof.png`.

#### 3. Open and edit it! it (done!)

#### Let's analyze what we have just done here:

Nautilus is the name of Ubuntu's native file browser. However, that file browser is desogned to protect crucial files that the system uses by only allowing access by root. That's when gksu comes along. When you open gksu along with something, it runs it as root. Being a root user and using a root file browser will enable you to modify **essential and crucial** parts of your system. That includes the icon you see at login.